# In .NET 6 Core, how can I create a HttpClient using the HttpClientFactory with a HttpClientHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclientfactory, ihttpclientfactory

I have the below code that I wish to transfer over to a .NET 6 Core.

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

// Setup the cookie container
handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

But instead of newing up the `HttpClient`, I want to use the `HttpClientFactory`. However, I can't figure how to use the `HttpClientFactory` with an existing instance of the `HttpClientHandler`.

I need the instance of the handler, since I use it with the `CookieContainer`.

I don't care if I use a DI instance of the `HttpClientFactory`, or if I can create the `HttpClient` instance directly in my `Program.cs`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use DI for this?

Comment: But, what is the syntax?  I mentioned DI in the question. I have created an HttpClient using builder.Services.AddHttpClient in a Program.cs file many times. However, I don't know how to do this with a HttpClientHandler.  Do you have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use HttpClientHandler with HttpClientFactory in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747749/how-to-use-httpclienthandler-with-httpclientfactory-in-net-core)

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I saw this answer. However it looks as though it is creating an instance of the HttpClientHander when it creates the HttpClient. How can I get the HttpClientHandler out of the HttpClient to set the CookieContainer?

Comment: [With reflection you can access it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999782/access-httpclienthandler-from-httpclient-instance)

Comment: See [Do pooled HttpClient instances keep the CookieContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227400/do-pooled-httpclient-instances-keep-the-cookiecontainer)